# WLED Device unable to discover in Xamarin forms iOS Apps

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

We have WLED mobile app on (Android/iOS) platforms. my issue  WLED device is working with android app and able to search/find WLED device through android app however iOS app unable to search the WLED device in iOS app and we are using iOS 16 version. both are same code on platforms

We tried to google for find the solution but didn't get it. want to be same work on iOS app with WLED device.

currently we used to xcode 14.2 latest and build iOS .ipa as well as tried to previous version 13.4 however same issue facing.

Eventhrogh we have upgrade the xamarin forms version 5.0 from older. after that notthing happend in app.

Comment: Please read [ask] before posting.  There is no useful information in your post that we could use to help you

Comment: May I ask how you search the WLED device, through Bluetooth?

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT we search the WLED device through Wifi by mbile app in same network. the only issue with only iPhone device even same code working in android platfrom.